# SQLite on latest PHP (>= 5.4)

Tags: php, pecl, sqlite

http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php

> Beginning with PHP 5.4, this extension is available only via PECL.

http://pecl.php.net/package/SQLite

> This package is not maintained anymore and has been superseded.

So, how am I supposed to get SQLite on PHP?

I guess downgrading to PHP 5.3 would work, but is that wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [release announcement](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php):

> ext/sqlite3 and ext/pdo_sqlite are not affected

Hence you should be converting your code to use sqlite3. There's a crude shim for the procedural API [in the comments here](http://php.net/manual/de/book.sqlite3.php).